# Tricky SQL update

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a tricky update to make. Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance for your help.

Here is the scenario as shown on the image attached. I have to update `P_main.ver_key` from `Versions.verkey` where `P_main.ver_key` is null. The logic is to get the `ver_key` for that `pid` where `Versions.pcmm <= max(P_main.vdmm)`. The values that should be populated in the null spots are shown in the 'after update' column on the image.

Example:

`P_main` table:

```
pid  = 50000178
vcmm = 2014027001
```

`Versions` table:

```
pid = 50000178
max pdmm <=2014027001 is 2014032000
```

therefore

```
update ver_key = 154
```

[image: sample data]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be the fastest way, but it should work:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT P.*, Q.ver_key ver_key_new
    FROM P_Main P
    CROSS APPLY(SELECT TOP 1 ver_key
                FROM Versions
                WHERE pid = P.pid
                AND vdmm <= P.vcmm
                ORDER BY vdmm DESC) Q
    WHERE P.ver_key IS NULL
)
UPDATE CTE
SET ver_key = ver_key_new;
```

Comment: This will update CTE, which I think is like a temp table. The I will have to update the physical table using CTE. Is that right?  Where do I add constraint for update only where ver_key is null?

Comment: No, this will update `P_Main`. For your condition, I updated my answer

Comment: Can you please flag the query with table aliases for the inner query for me to understand it more clearly.  I need P_Main.vcmm <= max(Versions pdmm).

Comment: sorry, I don't understand what you want (and you keep using `pdmm` when the image you posted shows `vdmm`)

Comment: Also, how can I apply  WHERE ver_key IS NULL constraint in the inner query so it uses a smaller data set in the cte?

Comment: I need P_Main.vcmm <= max(Versions vdmm).

Comment: alright, changed the condition `WHERE ver_key IS NULL` to the CTE. And now I'm done. Next time please ask the question with all your requirements

Comment: Thanks. That helps.